# Typescript object mapping for keys in child object

Tags: typescript

I have the following setup:

```
class Table{
    public values: DefaultTableValues;
}

class User extends Table{
    public values!: UserValues;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.values={username:'test', avatar:''}
    }
}

interface UserValues extends DefaultTableValues{
    avatar:string;
    username:string;
}
```

I am trying to add a `getColumns` method to `Table` that would return (for a User instance):
`{username:'username', avatar:'avatar'}`

This works:

```
public getColumns() {
        const copy = this.values;
        let arr = Object.keys(copy) as Array<keyof typeof copy>
        return arr.reduce((ac, a) => ({...ac, [a]: a}), {});
}
```

But Typescript/my IDE are not mapping it correctly. If I try something like `userInstance.getColumns().avatar` I get `property avatar does not exist on type {}`.

Is there a way to assert that `this.getColumns()` has the same keys as `this.values`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define the `values` in `Table` using generics:

```
class Table<T = DefaultTableValues>{
    public values!: T;

    public getColumns() {
        return this.values
    }
}
```

Then in `User` class

```
class User extends Table<UserValues> {
    public values!: UserValues;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.values = {username:'test', avatar:''}
    }
}
```

So, provided that `u` is a user instance, `u.getColumns()` would return `UserValues`

Comment: Thanks. I called the type `ValuesType` and got it to work with `public getColumns(): { [key in keyof ValuesType]: string }`